# Issues Stringifying a multidimensional array with json.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have problems with `.stringify()`, but I think my JavaScript array must be wrong, here's my code:

```
var questions = new Array();

$('#Valid').hover(function(){
    for (i=0;i < $('.Questions').length;i++){
        questions[i]=new Array();
        questions[i]['numero']=$('.Numero:eq('+i+')').html();
        questions[i]['question']=$('.ItemInput:eq('+i+')').val();
        questions[i]['variable']=$('.VarName:eq('+i+')').val();
    }

    var stringJSON=JSON.stringify(questions)
    alert (stringJSON)
})
```

The stringJSON var returns :

```
[[]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use `[]` instead of `new Array()`. Also you should **always** make your loop variable local using the `var` keyword!

Comment: `i < $('.Questions').length` is bad. You create a new jQuery object every loop. If your elements are descendants of `.Questions`, use `$('.questions').each(callback)`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Arrays have integer keys, not strings.

Use an object instead; objects in JS sort of look like associative arrays:

```
var questions = new Array();
$('#Valid').hover(function(){
    for (var i=0;i < $('.Questions').length;i++){
        questions[i]={};
        questions[i]['numero']=$('.Numero:eq('+i+')').html();
        questions[i]['question']=$('.ItemInput:eq('+i+')').val();
        questions[i]['variable']=$('.VarName:eq('+i+')').val();
    }

    var stringJSON=JSON.stringify(questions);
    alert(stringJSON);
});
```

Setting `questions[i]` to `{}` is the key.

You can shorten this syntax:

```
var questions = new Array();
$('#Valid').hover(function(){
    for (var i=0;i < $('.Questions').length;i++){
        questions[i] = {
            numero:   $('.Numero:eq('+i+')').html(),
            question: $('.ItemInput:eq('+i+')').val(),
            variable: $('.VarName:eq('+i+')').val()
        };
    }

    var stringJSON=JSON.stringify(questions);
    alert(stringJSON);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems so obvious now !

Comment: @Coronier: No problem. Arrays vs objects in JS are often confused.

Comment: this saved my life, literally. THANKS

Answer (score 6):

#### Fix:

Replace `questions[i]=new Array();` with `questions[i] = {};` (or `= new Object();` if you really want this "ugly" syntax).

#### Explanation:

Arrays in JavaScript are like arrays in languages like C: They only support integer indexes in the interval `[0, array.length)`.

For associative arrays, you use objects which are created using the object literal `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

First, your "questions" variable appears to be intended as a *real* array. What you're putting *inside* the array, however, are *not* real arrays — they're just objects with properties.

```
var questions = [];

$('#Valid').hover(function(){
    for (var i=0;i < $('.Questions').length;i++){
        questions[i] = {
          'numero': $('.Numero:eq('+i+')').html(),
          'question': $('.ItemInput:eq('+i+')').val(),
          'variable': $('.VarName:eq('+i+')').val()
        };
    }

    var stringJSON=JSON.stringify(questions)
    alert (stringJSON)
});
```

(Note that I also added a `var` for the "i" loop variable - important!)

Now, as to why the thing is coming up empty, well, I suspect it's because `$('.Questions')` is coming up empty.

Oh and also, this is something you could use the jQuery ".map()" API for:

```
 $('#Valid').hover(function() {
   questions = $('.Questions').map(function(i, q) {
     return {
       'numero': $('.Numero:eq('+i+')').html(),
       'question': $('.ItemInput:eq('+i+')').val(),
       'variable': $('.VarName:eq('+i+')').val()
     };
   }).get();

   var stringJSON = JSON.stringify(questions);
   alert(stringJSON);
});
```

That's a little nicer because it gets around the ugly problem of re-evaluating `$('.Questions')` on every iteration of the loop.