# Stringify with multidimensional array gives empty result

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array like this:

```
var d = new Array();
d[0] = new Array();
d[0]['item1'] = '123';
d[0]['item2'] = '456';
d[0]['item3'] = '789';
d[1] = new Array();
d[1]['item1'] = '123';
d[1]['item2'] = '456';
d[1]['item3'] = '789';
```

When using `console.log(JSON.stringify(d));` my console logs `"[[],[]]"`
Why does `JSON.stringify()` give an empty result?

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ky7CT/2/) showing my current situation

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168400/issues-stringifying-a-multidimensional-array-with-json-js). The answer is a solution, however my attribute names are variable, as you can see in the jsFiddle. Is there a way to make an attribute's name variable? Like this (doesn't work obviously):

```
var s = 'attrName';
var object = {
    s: '123'
}// The object should have an attribute named attrName
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issues Stringifying a multidimensional array with json.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168400/issues-stringifying-a-multidimensional-array-with-json-js)

Comment: You just can use bracket notation on objects as well. just start with `new Object()` or `{}` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
d[0] = {};
```

instead of:

```
d[0] = new Array();
```

This way `d[0]` is an object and not an array.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/FLDfR/

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because you are confusing `arrays` and `objects.`

While it is true that in JavaScript, arrays are just special objects but they are treated somewhat differently.

While this isn't *technically* true, pretend that arrays can only take integer keys, between 0 and 2^53.

```
// Tested in the console.
var d = [];
d[0] ={};
d[0]['item1'] = '123';
d[0]['item2'] = '456';
d[0]['item3'] = '789';
d[1] = {};
d[1]['item1'] = '123';
d[1]['item2'] = '456';
d[1]['item3'] = '789';

alert(JSON.stringify(d));
```

will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Going along with Jeremy J Starcher, you could just go full object with it:

```
var data = {
    '0': {
        'item1': '123'
    },
    '1': {
        'item1': 'abc'
    }
};
```

This will give you a better outcome, though not technically an array. =/

Answer (score 0):

To make the dynamic attribute you can use `[]` something like

```
var s = 'attrName';
var object = {};
object[s] = '123';
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/u69fE/)